# C code brings error for somewhat reason

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int item = 0;
    int buyovst = 0;    
    while (buyovst == 0) {
        printf("Do you want to 1. buy or 2.visit items or 3. to exit the shop?\n");
        scanf_s(" %d", &buyovst);

    if (buyovst == 1) {
        printf("What do you want to buy? you can only choose between the 4 items.\n");
        scanf_s(" %d", item);
        if(item > 0){
            if (item == 1) {
                printf("You bought Chips in 12$.\n");
            }
            if (item == 2) {
                printf("You bought Banana in 15$.\n");
            }
            if (item == 3) {
                printf("You bought a Book in 20$.\n");
            }
            if (item == 4) {
                printf("You bought a Pencil in 1$.\n");
            }
        }
        buyovst = 0;
    }
    if (buyovst == 2) {
        printf("There are 4 items on the shop.\n 1. Chips \t 12$\n 2.Banana \t 15$\n 3.Book \t 20$\n 4.Pencil \t 1$\n");
        buyovst = 0;
    }
    if (buyovst == 3) {
        printf("Goodbye!\n");
    }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

For somewhat reason I get this error:

[image: Debug Assertion Failed!]

I am trying to write a program that will ask the user if to

1. buy items
2. visit items
3. exit the shop.

If he chooses 1 --> he gets
asked what does he want to buy. if he picks 1 he gets chips 2 banana
 and so on... then he gets back to the first question (if to buy visit
 or exit) If he chooses 2 --> He sees the list of the items and their
 prices. then he gets back to the first question (if to buy visit or
 exit)

Comment: Why did you not point out to us which is line 1558?

Comment: Maybe because it's in *scanf_s* library code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
scanf_s(" %d", item);
```

is wrong. Pass the *pointer to* the variable instead of the *value of* the variable.

Replace the line with

```
scanf_s(" %d", &item);
```

(Add `&` before `item`)

Comment: Oh yeah!! I forgot to put the & before the item. Thank you very much.